# Official Maven repo for com.springsource.org.jboss.el

Tags: maven, jboss

I have a project with a dependency `org.jboss.el:com.springsource.org.jboss.el:jar:2.0.0.GA` for which I am trying to find the official Maven repository.

It is unclear to me where this depedency should come from. Should I download this and create a Nexus repo myself. Is there a official repo for this artifact?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project myjar:jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.jboss.el:com.springsource.org.jboss.el:jar:2.0.0.GA in https://mynexusserver/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact `org.jboss.el:com.springsource.org.jboss.el:jar:2.0.0.GA` is available from [Spring repositories](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.jboss.el&version=2.0.0.GA):

You can add them by adding this snippet inside your settings or POM:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```

Note that the error message you are getting suggest to run Maven with the `-U` option also, to force the updates of dependencies.